# Paste name of new columns when summarizing data.table

Tags: r, data.table

How to summarize a data.table creating new column whose name comes from a string or character?

#### reproducible example:

```
library(data.table)

dt <- data.table(x=rep(c("a","b"),20),y=factor(sample(letters,40,replace=T)), z=1:20)

i <- 15
new_var <- paste0("new_",i)

# my attempt
dt[, .( eval(new_var) = sum( z[which( z <= i)] )), by= x]

# expected result
dt[, .( new_15 = sum( z[which( z <= i)] )), by= x]

>    x new_15
> 1: a    128
> 2: b    112
```

This approach using `eval()` works fine for creating a new column with `:=` ([see this SO questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36101205/how-to-create-new-column-in-a-data-table-when-the-name-of-column-must-be-a-strin)), but I don't know why it does not work when summarizing a data.table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is `setNames`

```
dt[, setNames(.(sum( z[which( z <= i)])), new_var) , by= x]
#   x new_15
#1: a    128
#2: b    112
```

Comment: Thank you for reply @akrun, it works really well when I'm only summarizing one column. However, it doesn't work when I try to summarize more columns at the same time. For example: `dt[, .( other_var = mean(z) 
       , setNames( sum( z[which( z <= i)]), new_var)) , by= x]
`

Comment: @rafa.pereira  You need to place the `setNames` outside the `.(`